# How to create excel formula that will add an number to specific digits in a multi digit number

Tags: formula

Ex: I enter the number 9876543210 in a cell.
I want to create an if then formula to add a sequential number to this but working only off of the last digit. the zero in this example.

If the last digit is >= to 3 than add 5 if the last digit is <=2 than add 15.

Then have this formula repeat for 10 numbers - is that possible?
so i imput the 9876543210
it then show:
9876543225
9876543230
9876543245

and so on

Answer (score 1):

=IF((RIGHT(A1,1)/1)>2,A1+5,A1+15)

Assumed that you update the number in the cell A1.  Paste the above formula in A2 and copy paste downwards.

Comment: "If the last digit is >= to 3 than add 5 if the last digit is <=2 than add 15" is achieved by exactly this. I totally agree with you. However the test sets suggested by OP don't make sense with the logic he wrote down in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Excel, you may want to use MOD (modulo or remainder) function to get the last digit and then perform an IF-THEN or nested IF-THEN to achieve this.

```
=IF(MOD(A1,10)=3, A1+15, IF(MOD(A1,10)=5, A1+20, A1+30))
```

This formula translates to the following decision tree:

```
IF the last digit of the value in cell A3 is 3 Then
    Add 15 to it
ELSEIF the last digit of the value in cell A3 is 5 then
   Add 20 to it
ELSE
    Add 30 to it
END IF
```

Repeating the operation may require some VBA. If you already know the number of times you need to repeat the operation, you can pre-populate formulas in subsequent rows/columns, each time refer to the immediately preceding cell. For example, if you want to repeat it 5 times, you should compute the diff of first two cells and then add that diff to the value of immediately preceding row/column like this (assuming A1 had the original value, B1 had the formula I posted above and C1 through G1 are the next 5 cells):

In C1: `=B1 + ($B1 - $A1)`

In D1: `=C1 + ($B1 - $A1)`

and so on...

Note the use of absolute and relative addresses in these formulae. You can copy/paste the formula in C1 to the subsequent cells and it will automatically adjust itself to refer to immediately preceding cell.

**EDIT**

I just realized that you want to evaluate the MOD formula in each subsequent cell. In that case you simply need to copy/paste it to subsequent cells instead of using 2nd and 3rd formulas I posted above.